# Problem uninstalled and reinstall Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, uninstall, re-installation

I uninstalled using the Software Centre, but the minute I reinstalled Google Chrome, the extensions and everything were still there... How do I remove this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The config sits in `~/.config/google-chrome` so you can nuke that or move it out the way if you want to back it up. Here's nuking it:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
```